# how to speed up the scattering region calculation and transmission calculation in Transiesta

Tags: siesta

I am currently doing scattering region and transmission calculations using Siesta (4.1.5), the scattering region calculation is taking very long time to complete. I tried using different numbers of processors, like 48, 18, 36, etc., with paralleloverK as "true" and also tried divide and conquer as true , false, but I am unable to get faster results.

how can I increase the speed of my calculation.

Thankyou

Comment: Could you edit the question with more information? E.g. how many atoms do you have in the system, what is the k-grid that you use, what do you mean by "long time"...